# How to add custom js file in Magento 2 in custom theme without use module

Tags: magento2, javascript, custom

I used custom theme in magento 2. I want to add c**ustom js** file for navigation in magento 2 but js file not work.

I add `js` link in `default_head_block.xml` but a js doesn't work.

```
<link src="js/menu.js"/>
```

Comment: Don't do this, man. Use Magento devdocs https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/javascript-dev-guide/javascript/js_init.html. if you include scripts in this way - you will have a lot of problems.

Comment: @Gagan, could you please tell me how you succeeded in accomplishing this?

Answer (score 1):

create the file /app/design/frontend/Vendor/customtheme/Magento_Theme/layout/default_head_blocks.xml

assume you are trying to add bootstrap.js

File : **default_head_blocks.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <head>
         <!--Include js From CDN-->
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js" src_type="url" />
         <!--Include js From Custom module app/code/Company/Module/view/frontend/web/js-->
        <script src="Company_Module::js/bootstrap.min.js"/>        
    </head>
</page>
```

Please remove static files and flush magento cache

Comment: I want to add this script
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>

Comment: please update default_head_blocks.xml with
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js" src_type="url" />

Answer (score 0):

Goto your default.xml to the below location:

> app/design/frontend/Vendor/theme/Magento_Theme/layout/default.xml

And add the below code:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <head>
        <script src="Magento_Theme::js/custom.js"/>
    </head>
</page>
```

Now place your custom.js under below location:

> app/design/frontend/Vendor/theme/Magento_Theme/web/js/custom.js

Now you can add your to the js file as you want.

Comment: <?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <head>
         <script src="Magento_Theme::js/menu.js"/>
    </head>
</page>
Add js file but js file not loaded

Comment: Did you flush the cache? Also you need to run static-content:deploy as well.

Comment: @Sukumar Gorai, could you please have a look at my post regarding the similar task with slightly varying requirement at https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/312387/magento-2-how-to-insert-a-custom-js-file-in-the-header-of-custom-theme-this-cu

Answer (score 0):

The best way to add a `JS` in Magento (theme or module) is with **REQUIREJS**.

#### To add a js in **theme** via `Requirejs`:

Supposing that your js file is: `myfile.js`

**app/design/frontend/{Vendor}/{theme}/requirejs-config.js**

```
var config = {
    map: {
        '*': {
            myscript: 'js/myfile'
        }
    }
};
```

**app/design/frontend/{Vendor}/{theme}/web/js/myfile.js**

```
define(['jquery'], function($){
   "use strict";
       return function myscript()
       {
           alert('hello myscript');
           //put all your myfile js code here
       }
});
```

**app/design/frontend/{Vendor}/{theme}/Magento_Theme/templates/{yourfile}.phtml**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    require(['jquery', 'myscript'], function($, myscript) {
        myscript();
    });
</script>
```

**Info:** don't forget to :

- clean the cache
- clean `var/view_preprocessed` content
- clean `pub/static` content
- deploy the static content = `php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f`

Comment: what if I need to place the javascript url in the header of my Magento site?

Comment: could you please tell me if I can also use your method if I have placed the custom js file in a directory media/pmm-custom?

Comment: I don't want to keep my custom file here in app/design/frontend/{Vendor}/{theme}/web/js/.