# Magento 2: How to insert a custom JS file in the header of custom theme. This custom JS file is placed in pub/media/pmm-custom directory?

Tags: magento2.3, module, javascript, frontend, phtml

I'm looking for a way to add a custom js file in the header.phtml file. I don't place custom JS file under theme_directory for a obvious reason. Could anyone please tell me how to override header files to inset the custom JS file from pub/media/pmm-custom? To someone who may wonder why the custom JS has to be in pub/media/pmm-custom directory, it is only to help the client to push his minor changes that he often makes in the actual custom.js file residing under the theme_directory so that we don't have to build the Magento site every time he makes and pushes his changes made to this custom file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this is a JS file that will be edited outside of the Magento theme/static content deployment process it might be better to place the JS file somewhere else to stop if getting deleted/overwritten when you do those tasks.

I'd almost treat it as a 3rd party script and link to it using the script tag via XML:

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
  <head>
    <script src="LINK_TO_JS_File.js" src_type="url" />
  </head>
</page>
```

Comment: Readio, thanks a lot for the suggestion. I hope your suggestion will help achieve my task. To help you get the better understanding of the task, please have a look at the post that is an extension of this question at https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/312363/how-to-call-a-function-in-a-custom-js-file-from-within-another-custom-js-file